How much choice is needed for the Hat problem and how much is missing?
There is a 'well known' Problem in Math called the hat Problem where a countable infinite number of prisoners each get assigned a hat with colour red/blue and they have to guess their colour with only seeing the colours of everyone except their own.
The Question is if there exists a strategy such that only finitely many prisoners guess wrong and ZFC tells us yes there is.
My question now is, 'how much' choice does one need to prove this? Because i think DC is not enough, but what about e.g. the Compactness Theorem?
My second question would be, is there any (natural) generalization such that the existance of a solution would even be equivalent to choice? Like if there are arbitrary many people/hat coloures
Is there any literature about something like this?

Welcome to Math.SE! Does this answer your question: Infinite prisoners with hats -- is choice really needed? The compactness theorem (equivalently, the ultrafilter lemma) suffices to prove this. Read the answers given in the linked question carefully, and if the second part of your question is unanswered there, refocus this question around that.

@Z.A.K. I don't think the ultrafilter lemma does suffice; at least, I don't see that in the linked answers. Nate Eldridge claimed that but then retracted, see the edits to https://mathoverflow.net/a/184444/8133.

@NoahSchweber: Interesting, I might have been misremembering Eldridge's older version, and I don't actually know a proof from UL only. At least UL definitely suffices for the "people can hear each others' answers, you have to save all but one person" version, and the winning strategy for that version is in fact strictly weaker than the ultrafilter lemma (this I can actually justify). In any case, we do agree that the present Question 1 is a dupe of the linked question?

@Z.A.K. Yes, I agree re dupe. I don't see how UL is useful in the variant either, though, can you elaborate?

@NoahSchweber: See also Serafin which states this. I verified the ultrafilter lemma argument in Agda back in 2020, so Imm really quite sure of its correctness  (unpublished; was meant as a case study for a ThEdu article, but ThEdu was cancelled due to the pandemic).

@NoahSchweber: Rewrite of my previous comment, summarizing the argument. A nonstandard analytic proof: approximate $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ as $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}^k$  for some nonstandard integer $k$. The sum of such a nonstandard finite sequence is well-defined mod 2, and the standardization of this sum function yields a parity function on $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ , a two-valued function that changes its value whenever you change the color of exactlt one hat. You can use this to solve the problem exactly as you would in the finite sequence case.

@Z.A.K. Thanks, very nice argument! (For other readers: the UL is used to build the nonstandard setting used in Z.A.K.'s most recent comment.)
